# Slow Aggregates using as-of date

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a query that's intended as the base dataset for an AR Aging report in a BI tool. The report has to be able to show AR as of a given date across a several-month range. I have the logic working, but I'm seeing pretty slow performance. Code below:

```
WITH 
    DAT AS (
        SELECT
            MY_DATE AS_OF_DATE
        FROM
            NS_REPORTS."PUBLIC".NETSUITE_DATE_TABLE
        WHERE
            CAST(CAST(MY_DATE AS TIMESTAMP) AS DATE) BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND CAST(CAST(CURRENT_DATE() AS TIMESTAMP) AS DATE)
    ), INV AS
    (
        WITH BASE AS
            (
                SELECT
                    BAS1.TRANSACTION_ID
                  , DAT.AS_OF_DATE
                  , SUM(BAS1.AMOUNT) ORIG_AMOUNT_BASE
                FROM
                    "PUBLIC".BILL_TRANS_LINES_BASE BAS1
                    CROSS JOIN DAT
                WHERE
                    BAS1.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'Invoice'
                    AND BAS1.TRANSACTION_DATE <= DAT.AS_OF_DATE
                    --AND BAS1.TRANSACTION_ID = 6114380
                GROUP BY
                    BAS1.TRANSACTION_ID
                    , DAT.AS_OF_DATE
            )
          , TAX AS
            (
                SELECT
                    TRL1.TRANSACTION_ID
                  , SUM(TRL1.AMOUNT_TAXED * - 1) ORIG_AMOUNT_TAX
                FROM
                    CONNECTORS.NETSUITE.TRANSACTION_LINES TRL1
                WHERE
                    TRL1.AMOUNT_TAXED IS NOT NULL
                    AND TRL1.TRANSACTION_ID IN (SELECT TRANSACTION_ID FROM BASE)
                GROUP BY
                    TRL1.TRANSACTION_ID
            )
        SELECT
            BASE.TRANSACTION_ID
          , BASE.AS_OF_DATE
          , BASE.ORIG_AMOUNT_BASE
          , COALESCE(TAX.ORIG_AMOUNT_TAX, 0) ORIG_AMOUNT_TAX
        FROM
            BASE
            LEFT JOIN TAX ON TAX.TRANSACTION_ID = BASE.TRANSACTION_ID
    )
SELECT
    AR.*
  , CASE
        WHEN AR.DAYS_OUTSTANDING < 0
            THEN 'Current'
        WHEN AR.DAYS_OUTSTANDING BETWEEN 0 AND 30
            THEN '0 - 30'
        WHEN AR.DAYS_OUTSTANDING BETWEEN 31 AND 60
            THEN '31 - 60'
        WHEN AR.DAYS_OUTSTANDING BETWEEN 61 AND 90
            THEN '61 - 90'
        WHEN AR.DAYS_OUTSTANDING > 90
            THEN '91+'
            ELSE NULL
    END DO_BUCKET
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            AR1.*
          , TRA1.TRANSACTION_TYPE
          , DATEDIFF('day', AR1.AS_OF_DATE, CAST(CAST(TRA1.DUE_DATE AS TIMESTAMP) AS DATE)) DAYS_OUTSTANDING
          , AR1.ORIG_AMOUNT_BASE + AR1.ORIG_AMOUNT_TAX + AR1.PMT_AMOUNT                    AMOUNT_OUTSTANDING
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    INV.TRANSACTION_ID
                  , INV.AS_OF_DATE
                  , INV.ORIG_AMOUNT_BASE
                  , INV.ORIG_AMOUNT_TAX
                  , COALESCE(PMT.PMT_AMOUNT, 0) PMT_AMOUNT
                FROM
                    INV
                    LEFT JOIN (
                      SELECT
                          TLK.ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_ID
                        , DAT.AS_OF_DATE
                        , SUM(TLK.AMOUNT_LINKED * - 1) PMT_AMOUNT
                      FROM
                          CONNECTORS.NETSUITE."TRANSACTION_LINKS" AS TLK
                          CROSS JOIN DAT
                      WHERE
                          TLK.LINK_TYPE = 'Payment'
                          AND CAST(CAST(TLK.ORIGINAL_DATE_POSTED AS TIMESTAMP) AS DATE) <= DAT.AS_OF_DATE
                      GROUP BY
                          TLK.ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_ID
                          , DAT.AS_OF_DATE
                  ) PMT ON PMT.ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_ID = INV.TRANSACTION_ID
                        AND PMT.AS_OF_DATE = INV.AS_OF_DATE
            ) AR1
            JOIN CONNECTORS.NETSUITE."TRANSACTIONS" TRA1 ON TRA1.TRANSACTION_ID = AR1.TRANSACTION_ID
    )
    AR
WHERE
    1 = 1
    --AND CAST(AMOUNT_OUTSTANDING AS NUMERIC(15, 2)) > 0
    AND AS_OF_DATE >= '2020-04-22'
```

As you can see, I'm using a date table for the as-of date logic. I think this is the best way to do it, but I welcome any suggestions for better practice.

If I run the query with a single as-of date, it takes 1 min 6 sec and the two main aggregates, on TRANSACTION_LINKS and BILL_TRANS_LINES_BASE, each take about 25% of processing time. I'm not sure why. If I run with the filter shown, `>= '2020-04-22'`, it takes 3 min 33 sec and the aggregates each take about 10% of processing time; they're lower because the ResultWorker takes 63% of processing time to write the results because it's so many rows.

I'm new to Snowflake but not to SQL. My understanding is that Snowflake does not allow manual creation of indexes, but again, I'm happy to be wrong. Please let me know if you have any ideas for improving the performance of this query.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**
[Screenshot of most expensive node in query profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NCkC.png)

Comment: In the History screen; click on the query ID for the query profile. Check the execution plan for anything that looks inefficient. Each node of the tree will display the % of time each took. For any node that has a significant % of execution time, click on it and check for efficient partition pruning. If you see that the scan is looking at all or most of the partitions, you should consider a one-time rebuild of the table(s) with an order by on the key date field or using auto clustering with a key set to that column.https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html

Comment: @GregPavlik I already looked at the execution plan; that's how I knew the percentages of processing time I mentioned. Having read through the link you provided, I don't think the table is large enough to merit a clustering key; the query only returns 35 million rows and that's counting the "as-of" logic which repeats many of the rows in the base data tables for each date in the range. For whatever reason, it's specifically the aggregation that's slowing it down.

Comment: A screen shot of the profile with the details of the aggregation step would help.  What size warehouse are you using?  Is there spilling to remote storage during the execution?  Also, don't dismiss the benefits of clustering the table, particularly if the table can be clustered on the date that you are using.  Lastly, do you see any examples where your joins are producing records (many-to-many) that might benefit from a different join or a SQL rewrite to allow Snowflake to prune better before the join?

Comment: @MikeWalton this is strange. 

a) I notice today that the query runs significantly faster in the Snowflake browser client than in DBeaver - 10 secs in Snowflake vs over a minute in DBeaver (DBeaver says 27 secs but it took quite a bit longer than that in reality). 

b) the query profile has changed completely from last week. Now the highest-cost node is a table scan rather than the aggregates I mentioned previously. I have not removed the aggregates. I did do some tinkering with the query, but I don't think I made any changes that would have such a huge impact.

Comment: @MikeWalton to answer your other questions: "What size warehouse are you using?" I don't know how to determine this. I am new to Snowflake. "Is there spilling to remote storage during the execution?" Ibid. "SQL rewrite to allow Snowflake to prune better before the join" I wonder if one of the changes I made accomplished this unintentionally and that's why the performance is so much better today and the query profile so different vs last week. I'll post a screenshot of the most expensive node above.

Comment: @MikeCaputoRegarding the difference between DBeaver and the UI, plus the fact that it says it took 27 seconds, is highly likely that the rest of the time was the amount of time it took to get the results to DBeaver vs. the UI.  The UI will limit the amount of records returned, while DBeaver is getting all of the records.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full explain plan and having some sample data to play with it is difficult to give any definitive answers, but here a few thoughts, for what they are worth...

The first are more about readability and may not help performance much:

1. Don't embed CTEs within each other, just define them in the order that they are needed. There is no need to define BASE and TAX within INV
2. Use CTEs as much as possible. Your main SELECT statement has 2 other SELECT statements embedded within it. It would be much more readable if these were defined using CTEs

Specific performance issues:

1. Keep data volumes as low as possible for as long as possible. Your CROSS JOINs obviously create cartesian products that massively increases the volume of data - therefore implement this as late in your SQL as possible rather than right at the start as you have done
2. While it may make your SQL less readable, use as few SQL statements as possible. For example, you should be able to create your INV CTE with a single SELECT statement rather than the 3 statements/CTEs that you are using